# How to compute the series: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\binom{1/2}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

I'm wondering about how to show compute this series: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\binom{1/2}{n}$$

My approach was to use the general formula of the binomial series, which is: $$(1+z)^r=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}z^{k}\binom{r}{k}$$

Yet this can't be used because in this case, we have $|z|=1$.
Thus, is there any method that I can use for this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem

Comment: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%28-1%29%5E%28k-1%29*%7B1%2F2+%5Cchoose+k%7D+for+k%3D0..n) finds the partial sum somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You 'incororate' it into the binomial coefficient, e.g. for
$$
(1+z)^{-\frac{1}{2}} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{k}z^k
$$
It is $(-1)^{k}\frac{(2k-1)!!}{k!2^k}$